# Modifying combo-boxes when linked with Datasource

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio

What I am currently trying to do:
"Display all the categories via the Category_ComboBox along with their primary_Key, so that the combobox value for that option would contain the primary key of that row > Allowing for a check to occur to see if that row of data has a sub_category or not."

How the datasource data looks:

[image: How the datasource data looks]

How the Category/Sub_Category_ComboBox's currently displays:

[image: How the Category/Sub_Category_ComboBox's currently displays]

The data is currently being drawn in from the SQL datasource, which means that something like

```
Category_ComboBox.Items.Add(new { cat.Key, cat.Category } )
```

will not work. I am presuming I'll have to do something similar to this:

```
Category_ComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof()).Cast<>();
```

OR should I just remove itemsource and have it add the values in through the back-end code? Exception I'm getting:

```
Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use.
Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead
```

Can clarify further if that doesn't make sense.

Entire Code, for reference:

C#:

```
/*
* What we're trying to do:
* 
* First, determine whether or not the row(s) data for the Category column have data for the Sub_Category column or if the Category data contains the same values (names, EX: BillTrak Pro), then sort them accordingly.
** Sub_Categories should only Sync with their corresponding Categories, not all Categories.
* 
* 
* Conditionals for the Category data pertaining to Sub_Category(s):
** If no Sub_Category(s) exist for the WHOLE Category, then > Sub_Category_ComboBox should be set to read ONLY(IsEnabled = false) and the four ListView's should just display single Category Information.
* 
* 
** If Category(s) contain Sub_Category(s), then SubCategory_ComboBox should display only the Sub_Categories that are Sync'd to the specific Category(s).
* Row Data should be sorted, first by Category, then Sub_Category, then displayed only when their Sub_Category is displayed via the SubCategory_ComboBox.
* The four ListView's data should only display data, coresponding to the SubCategory_ComboBox data.
* 
*/


namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

WpfApplication1.DataSet1 dataSet1 = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet1)(this.FindResource("dataSet1")));
        // Load data into the table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter dataSet1OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter();
        dataSet1OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource")));
        oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2 dataSet2 = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet2)(this.FindResource("dataSet2")));
        // Load data into the table OP_TITLE_INFORMATION. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter dataSet2OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter();
        dataSet2OP_TITLE_INFORMATIONTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet2.OP_TITLE_INFORMATION);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource oP_TITLE_INFORMATIONViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("oP_TITLE_INFORMATIONViewSource")));
        oP_TITLE_INFORMATIONViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        // Load data into the table OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter dataSet2OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter();
        dataSet2OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet2.OP_MAIN_COLLECTIONS);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource1 = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource1")));
        oP_MAIN_COLLECTIONSViewSource1.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Operations Guide Name Display settings.
     */
    private void OPGuideName_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Category_ComboBox Display settings.
     */
    private void Category_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**
         * TO-DO:
         * Determine whether or not the row(s) data for the Category column have data for the Sub_Category column
         * or if the Category data contains the same values (names, EX: BillTrak Pro), then sort them accordingly.
         */


        WpfApplication1.DataSet2 DS = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet2)(this.FindResource("dataSet2")));

        var cats = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { Key = r.Field<decimal>("Primary_Key"), Category = r.Field<string>("Category") }).ToList();

        foreach (var cat in cats)
        {
            //Add category and primary key to combo box
            Category_ComboBox.Items.Add(new { cat.Key, cat.Category } );
        }

  //      foreach (DataRow rows in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
  //      {
  //          decimal primary_key = rows.Field<decimal>("Primary_Key");
  //          string category = rows.Field<string>("Category");
  //
  //          //populate the combo box
  //          Category_ComboBox.Items.Add(new { primary_key, category } );
  //      }

        int id = 1; //Get form category combox
        DataRow row = DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<decimal>("Primary_Key") == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (row != default(DataRow))
        {
            if (row["sub_category"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                //There is a sub category
                MessageBox.Show("Reached");
                SubCategory_ComboBox.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //sub category is null
                SubCategory_ComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //selected category id does not exists
        }
    }


    /**
     * SubCategory_ComboBox Display settings.
     */
    private void SubCategory_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**
         * Purpose:
         * Should convert SubCategory_ComboBox to readOnly(IsEnabled = false)
         * if the data contained in the SubCategory SQL Column is null && Category doesn't contain any Sub_Categories.
         * Else, display SubCategory_ComboBox as normal, sync'd with the corresponding category name.
         * 
         * Currently, This code disables the subcategory combobox completely.
         * Need to figure out how to get it to read ONLY the null data, not the entire column.
         */
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubCategory_ComboBox.Text))
        {
            SubCategory_ComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void sCHEDULEListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```